# Autofac and RegisterGeneric - limit allowed generics

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Let's say that I have a generic registration with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Injectator<>))
       .As(typeof(IInjectator<>))
       .SingleInstance();
```

Now (I)Injectator has single generic. But I don't want every possible class or struct to be allowed as generic.

I only want it for classes, that inherit from some specified class:

```
class JustClass { // not allowed
}

class SpecialClass : InjectableClass { // allowed
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a constraint on your generic interface :

```
public interface IInjectator<T> 
    where T : InjectableClass 
{ }
```

This way .net won't allow you to get an invalid type.

If you can't do this, there is no easy way to change the behavior of `RegisterGeneric` one way I can see is to subscribe to the `OnActivated` event and throw an exception :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Foo<>))
        .As(typeof(IFoo<>))
        .OnActivated(e =>
        {
            Boolean isValid = e.Component.Services
                .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
                .Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsConstructedGenericType
                            && s.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IFoo<>)
                            && s.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableTo<IBar>())
                .Any();

            if (!isValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("boom");
            }
        });
```

If you don't want to throw an exception you can implement your own `IRegistrationSource`. You can have a look at the source code of the native [`OpenGenericRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/41044d7d1a4fa277c628021537d5a12016137c3b/src/Autofac/Features/OpenGenerics/OpenGenericRegistrationSource.cs) which resolves open generic types.

Comment: I went with constraint way.